# javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com... with id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I'm currently working on migrating a project from Hibernate XML mapping to JPA annotations. I solved the most but I got a problem with one of the relations. The original XML mapping was:

```
<set name="projectCopies">
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com...Project"/>
</set>
```

I have annotated the set like:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id") 
private Set<Project> projectCopies=new HashSet<Project>();
```

It seems to be working when I look at the DB:

```
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+ 
| HIBERNATE_ID | name                     | parent_id |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+ 
|            4 | Test_project             |      NULL | 
|            5 | Test_project_copy        |         4 |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------+
```

The problem is it works only the first time when I add a copy of the Project. After I delete the copy and try to add a new copy instead I get the following error:

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   com...Project with id 5

I tried to fix in many ways but nothing worked. I would appreciate any ideas.

Some code:

```
public final Project getMyCopy() {
    if (!hasCopy()) {
        return this;
    }
    return copies.iterator().next();
}

protected final void clearCopies() {
    if (hasCopy()) {
        delete(getMyCopy());  <-- delete method only contains: JpaStore.PROJECT.delete(project.getId());
    }
    copies.clear();
    copyDate=0;
    JpaStore.PROJECT.merge(this);
}


public final void copy() {
    try {
        if (hasCopy()) {
            clearCopies();
        }
        final Project copy=this.clone();
        copy.name=makeCopyName(name);
        copy.stampDate=COPY_COPYDATE;
        setCopyDate();
        setMyCopy(copy);
        save();  <-- save method only contains: JpaStore.PROJECT.merge(this);

    } catch (final CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(""+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to delete an existing projectCopy and adding the same again? Can you show the code where you are trying to do delete & add?

Comment: @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu No, I delete an existing projectCopy and then I create a new one of the parent and add that instead. I reverted nearly everything so it's nearly the original code which I started to work with. The only difference is that I changed Hibernate save/delete to JpaStore class which uses EntityManager.